# Why use the pattern (_:_) instead of a simple wildcard, in this case?

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching, empty-list

As I was scanning through [`GHC.List.hs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/GHC-List.html), I came across the following [definition for `null`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/GHC-List.html#null):

```hs
-- | Test whether a list is empty.
null                    :: [a] -> Bool
null []                 =  True
null (_:_)              =  False
```

I'm surprised that the second equation isn't simply

```hs
null _                  =  False
```

This alternative equation is syntactically valid and would not change the semantics of `null`: because the first pattern is the empty list, the second pattern would only be used if the argument is a nonempty list. Moreover, in my opinion, this alternative equation is simpler and more readable. Which begs the question:

**Is there a particular reason why the pattern `(_:_)` is used instead of a wildcard, here?**

(If this is a form of optimization, please elaborate.)

Comment: The answer to this kind of strangeness is usually "laziness", but it seems that the cons operator would be eval'd when pattern matching against the empty list constructor, so I'm not sure why you'd need it in the second pattern...

Comment: I think the answer is simple: The principle of least surprise. It's simply _clearer_ if you write it as `(_,_)` rather than having to infer it yourself.

Comment: I think it's just a matter of personal preference. For instance, I wouldn't define `not True = False ; not _ = True`, preferring to specify the last case explicitly. Whichever is the style, the generated code should be exactly the same, so it does not affect performance.

Comment: Whether or not to use the wildcard pattern match is more of an issue for types that are in flux (i.e. that might add constructors later).  If you use the wildcard match as your last branch then the compiler won't warn you if you add new constructors to your type, whereas an explicit pattern match for all branches would generate a compiler warning if you added new unmatched constructors.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez Thanks; that makes a lot of sense. That said, the list type can hardly said to be a "in flux", at this stage.

Comment: @Jubobs Right.  For stable types like list it boils down to personal preference